# Improve circle detection for a spicific color in python opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to use Hough Transform to detect the purple circle (purple pollen) in this image.

[image]

But the results show that it also detecteted the other factors.

[image]

What should I do to improve this circle detection?

Here is my code:

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

def circle_detect(path, filename):

    iml = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


    img = image_resize(iml,height=960)
    img_array = np.array(img)

    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cimg = cv2.medianBlur(cimg,5)

    #Circle detection to detect pollen in big images, return the center's coordinates and radius of circles in array
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=15,param2=20,minRadius=10,maxRadius=25)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))[0,:]
    for j in range(len(circles)):
        cv2.circle(img,(circles[i][0],circles[i][1]),circles[i][2],(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imwrite("export_circle/"+"output"+filename,img)
```

Comment: What is the problem with current implementation? Are there false positives? Are they overlapping? Are some obvious circles missing?

Comment: It's false positive. I just want to detect the purple ones.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you play with a color image it is better to opt for HSV color space. For the image provided, I converted the image to HSV and obtained the hue channel. Find circles on this hue channel.

**Code:**

```
import cv2

im1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\pollen.jpg')
#--- convert to hsv color space ---
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

im2 = im1.copy()

#--- find circles in the hue channel ---
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(hsv[:,:,0],cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 75, param1=15, param2=30, minRadius=0,maxRadius=400)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(im2,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(im2,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow("im2", im2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

You will have to tweak the parameters to find the circles properly